# Using CommonUI Plugin in Unreal Engine5 does not show any option in PlatformInput

Tags: unreal, plugin

As shown in the following screenshot, the menu **Platform Input** does not show any information and does not allow any customization.

[image: Common Input Settings - Not working]

Following the steps in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTB5y-03SnE) the options are necessary to configure part of the UI key binding, they should be visible as you can see at minute 38:50 or in the following screenshot: [image: Working Settings].

Does anyone know if this is a bug or am I missing some piece? Does not seem to be required any other plugin.

Comment: How have you configured what platforms this project should target?

Comment: My only configured platform is windows, I updated it recently but to make it refresh correctly I had to delete all temporary files and recompile the project. That was a good hint, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue wasn't a bug, I had to enable at least one platform to make those settings appear. It requires, also, to delete temporary files such as **Binary** folder and then recreating the source project files and recompile the project.